# Picard/Crusher Love Scene

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, episode-identification, jean-luc-picard

I saw a preview where Picard & Crusher were lying on the ground, Picard saying, "I love you,  Beverly. I've always loved you." What episode/film is this from?

Comment: Crusher isn't in *ST: Picard*

Comment: Am I the only one whose brain jumped to Wesley instead of Beverly?

Comment: @FuzzyBoots No, Picard's love for Wesley [was different](https://i.pinimg.com/originals/50/83/bf/5083bf62ace3b8017ea2219e0e5acc6b.jpg)

Answer (score 29):

The closest any episode comes to exploring the Crusher-Picard love interest was the episode [Attached](http://www.chakoteya.net/NextGen/260.htm). Picard and Crusher are captured and neurally linked. When Crusher picks up on Picard's thoughts, he admits he had feelings for her and, after an awkward conversation, they lie next to each other to rest. He never says he "always loved her", but states that their relationship has changed to something more platonic over time. Emphasis mine

> CRUSHER: I remember when Jack and I took Wesley on his first camping trip to Balfour Lake. Wesley kept throwing manta leaves in the fire, watching them pop. Jack kept telling him. What? Jean-Luc, I heard you. Don't push it away. When I said Jack and I, I felt this sudden wave of something. I didn't know you felt that way.
> PICARD: Didn't you?
> CRUSHER: I guess I always knew that there was an attraction between us right from the start, but I never knew how strongly you felt. **Why didn't you ever tell me you were in love with me?**
> PICARD: You were married to my best friend. **At first I thought it was harmless infatuation. Something hormonal rather than emotional.**
> CRUSHER: Then when the months went by and the three of us began spending more time together.
> PICARD: **I realised that it was something else, and it wasn't right. But although I would never act on it, I couldn't help the way I felt.**
> CRUSHER: And when Jack died you felt guilty.
> PICARD: I felt guilty before he died. Having feelings like that for my best friend's wife. And then later, after the accident, I promised myself that I would never tell you how I felt. It would be like betraying my friend
> CRUSHER: That's why you didn't want me on the Enterprise seven years ago.
> PICARD: I didn't know how I would react. And then, little by little, I realised that I didn't have those feelings any more. Twenty years is, after all, a long time.
> CRUSHER: And now we're friends.
> PICARD: Yes, friends.
> CRUSHER: Well, we still have a lot of ground to cover tomorrow. We should get some sleep.
> PICARD: Right.
> **(Beverly lies down near the fire, then Picard lies next to her)**

I should note [All Good Things...](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/All_Good_Things..._(episode)), the series finale, hinted at a rekindling, but that was an alternate timeline and does not match the description

Comment: There was an episode which flashed forward to the future, where Crusher commands her own medical frigate, and she and Picard are now *divorced*, implying that they were married at some point between then and the show's present.  I want to say it was the series finale?

Comment: @DarrelHoffman Correct, it was in *All Good Things*.

Comment: @DarrelHoffman It was ([All Good Things...](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/All_Good_Things..._(episode))). The catch here is that this scene matches the episode description. I don't recall older Picard ever laying down with older Crusher, though

Comment: Right, just saying that this would be another episode that *"explores the Crusher-Picard love interest"*, if only in retrospect.

Comment: @Shade Is it certain that "I would never tell you know how I felt" is a typo for "I would never tell you how I felt" rather than"I would never let you know how I felt"? I never watched that silly show, but the latter correction seems more likely on general principles.